# Spring Data returning List<Object[]>

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data

I have this repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>{

@Query("SELECT p.textToSearch as text, count(*) as counter FROM Product p GROUP BY text_to_search ORDER BY counter DESC")
List<TopProductDTO> findTopProducts();
}
```

where the TopProductDTO class is:

```
public class TopProductDTO {

public TopProductDTO() {}

private String text;
private Integer counter;

// Getters and Setters are omited
}
```

But when I execute the code

```
List<TopProductDTO> topProducts = productRepository.findTopProducts();
```

It returns a

```
List<Object[]> insted a List<TopProductDTO>
```

As like each column is a index of the Object Array in the list... 
Wasn't it supposed to Spring Data binds the 'text' and 'counter' columns from query with the fields in TopProductDTO?

As result I got a this error in my Thymeleaf Template:

```
00:37:22.659 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "topProductDTO.text" (products/top:46)] with root cause
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 14): Property or field 'text' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.Object[]' - maybe not public?
```

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.3 and Postgres 9.2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to use the constructor of your DTO.

Declare a new constructor

```
public TopProductDTO(String text, Integer count) {
    this.text = text;
    this.count = count;
}
```

In your query use the new Constructor

```
@Query("SELECT new TopProductDTO(p.textToSearch, count(id))FROM Product p GROUP BY text_to_search ORDER BY counter DESC")
List<TopProductDTO> findTopProducts();
}
```

Use the fully qualified name of your class.

Comment: At [hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) you can see some good examples too.

Comment: When I do this, compilation fails with error `Validation failed for query...`. There is no other stack trace that makes sense. Any ideas why should that be happening?

Comment: What is the full validation error message? Make sure you prefix your class package name, as mentioned before

Comment: This issue made me not able to think straight. The solution works like a charm, Thank you.

Comment: Is it advisable to use DTO  at Repository layer? Shouldn't object[] be converted to DTO at service layer?