# Refactoring in Spring Data returning List<Object[]>

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I've been working in legacy project that has several repository methods like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT "
        + "  i.uf, "
        + "  i.cidade "
        + "FROM Imovel AS i "
        + "WHERE i.ativo = 'Sim' AND "
        + "      EXISTS (SELECT 1 "
        + "              FROM ImovelFoto AS f "
        + "              WHERE f.codigoImovel = i.codigo)"
        + "GROUP BY i.uf, i.cidade", nativeQuery = true)    
List<Object[]> findUFCidade();
```

I would like to change it to an object like this:

```
public class LocalizacaoAgrupadaDTO {

    private String uf;
    private String cidade;

    // Getters e Setters omitidos
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35714286/5230740) suggest changing `nativeQuery` for `JPQL`.

However, this change add an extra complexity due to the different syntax and the entities mapping, since this select clause is a groupping with no direct relation to entities.

**What is the best way to refactoring this use of Spring Data JPA?**

Should I always try to use JPQL or can I use nativeQuery??

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a "Best" way to refactor this using Spring Data JPA. There is just a spectrum of options that you can choose from.

I think the most "ideal" / modern option, though likely the most time consuming, would be to switch to using properly mapped objects and JPQL.

Your result wouldn't need to be an `@Entity` object itself though, you could use syntax like `SELECT new LocalizacaoAgrupadaDTO(e.uf, e.cidade) FROM EntityObject e ...<rest of JPQL query` to return the result of your query as a specific DTO type.

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select

Answer (score 0):

Create a [custom repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) and than use the [ResultTransformer](http://in.relation.to/2006/03/17/hibernate-32-transformers-for-hql-and-sql/).

[Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2445176/3038067).

And you gone need get the object Session from hibernate from the EntityManager,[here a example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4151834/3038067).